# How can I make multiselected on html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

More button is a dropdown, opens on More click. I would like to make More has multiple checkboxes. I have written on html codes: multiselected element and have tried to click caret sign then website doesn't allow to open checkboxes list.

My code HTML/CSS/JS visit   http://jsfiddle.net/y57gdwsL/7/

Here is my code.

```
<multiselect class="input-xlarge" multiple="true"
                    ng-model="selectedCar"
                    options="c.name for c in cars"
                    change="selected()" ></multiselect>
                <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn" ng-click="toggleSelect()" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-class="{'error': !valid()}"> 
                            <span class="pull-left">More </span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li ng-repeat="i in items | filter:searchText">
                            <a ng-click="select(i); focus()">
                            <i ng-class="{'icon-ok': i.checked, 'icon-empty': !i.checked}"></i>{{i.label}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
```

Can everyone help me for passing multiselected element?

Comment: [html multiselect](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple), if you want something more fancy, you can use the multiselect from bootstrap

Comment: [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), you might use JQuery plugin for multiselect.